# AngularJs prevent user from selecting negative numbers

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way to prevent a selection of a non-positive/negative number in the  element?

Comment: which element are you talking about? input text ?

Comment: <input type="number" min="1" ng-model="number">

Answer (score 0):

try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/8UBLR/

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.wks =  {number: 1, validity: true}
});

app.directive('isNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope) {    
            scope.$watch('wks.number', function(newValue,oldValue) {
                var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    scope.wks.number = oldValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

<form ng-app="myapp" name="myform" novalidate> 
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input name="number" is-number ng-model="wks.number">
    <span ng-show="!wks.validity">Value is invalid</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The only issue that I have with this is  scope.$watch('wks.number') it makes it work for only one type of binding

Answer (score -3):

You can use **regex** to specify the type of input you expect from a user.